# cross-(sub)domain jQuery.ajax query to flask app receives cookies but can't send them

Tags: ajax, session, flask, cookies

I have two domains:

```
https://localhost.com     # SPA served via Nginx
https://api.localhost.com # Flask API proxied by nginx (uwsgi_pass)
```

and added both to my hosts file via `127.0.0.1 localhost.com api.localhost.com`.

I've added server-side oauth2 via GitHub's oauth service and I'm able to authenticate (I receive an access token and can query the GitHub API). This is the "flow":

```
user calls: https://localhost.com
ajax: https://api.localhost.com/v1/login # gets the app's Github OAuth url
                                         # sets a session cookie for
                                         # localhost.com
user calls: https://github.com/...       # gets redirected to log in ect.
redirect: https://api.localhost.com/callback 
                                         # github redirects to the callback
                                         # can access some session cookie 
                                         # (I assume) from localhost.com
redirect: https://localhost.com          # now has two session cookies:
                                         # localhost.com
                                         # api.localhost.com
ajax: https://api.localhost.com/v1/username 
                                         # this is where it breaks
```

I set both, the server-side `CORS` headers for `api.localhost.com` (snippet from nginx.conf)

```
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "https://localhost.com";
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type, *';
```

and the `withCredentials` parameter in the queries:

```
    $.getJSON("https://api.localhost.com/v1/login", 
    {
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    },
    (response) => {
        this.login_url = response;
    });
    $.getJSON("https://api.localhost.com/v1/username", 
    {
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    },
    (response) => {
        console.log(response)
        this.username = response;
    });
```

The first cross-domain `ajax: https://api.localhost.com/v1/login` works and sets a cookie, so I think it's configured correctly. (I might be wrong.)
However, the second `ajax: https://api.localhost.com/v1/username` doesn't seem to send the session cookie, as I am left with an empty session in flask:

```
from flask import session

# [ ... ]

def username_get():
    return str(list(session.keys())) # returns "[]"
```

I can manually decrypt both session cookies (`localhost.com` and `api.localhost.com`). They both have the same content (username, access token and oauth_state [required during GitHub OAuth]) and indicate that authentication was successful.

What I don't understand is:

1. Why do I get two cookies, in particular why is the session cookie from `ajax: https://api.localhost.com/v1/login` stored in `localhost.com` and not `api.localhost.com`?
2. Github OAuth is working, meaning `redirect: https://api.localhost.com/callback` receives the session cookie set by `https://api.localhost.com/v1/login` and can use the data (oauth_state). However the subsequent `ajax: https://api.localhost.com/v1/Username` does not send the session cookie. Why?

I hope I've included all the necessary bits. This is a very puzzling problem and none of the existing SO questions helped me past this point. ANY help or pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(2) I was using `$.getJSON` wrong. It's so simple that it hurts.

As [per the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

```
jQuery.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success ] )
```

and data will be appended to the URL as a query parameter. Thus replacing the call with

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "https://api.localhost.com/v1/username",
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
        success: (response) => 
        {
            this.username = response;
        }
      });
```

(not using the shorthand) sets the appropriate `xhrField` and now correctly sends the cookie.

(1) Probably caused by caching or some temporary files. I brought down the entire server, cleared all temp files and did the same with my browser (Chrome). After restarting, I only get a single session cookie for `api.localhost.com` which is the expected behavior.